# Disable Delegate Access in Outlook / Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2007

I've found that you can disable delegate access individually, on each client, through the Add-ins menu, under Exchange Client Extensions. However, we do not want any of our users to be able to use delegate access, so would like to disable it company-wide.

Does anyone know of a way to do this, either through Exchange or group policy?

Both Exchange and the Outlook clients are version 2007.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but a regkey may work through GPO:

http://msexchangegeek.com/2009/06/03/how-to-prevent-users-from-delegating-their-own-mailboxes/

Comment: I hadn't actually found that one yet, but it's not working for me - doesn't seem to have any effect at all. Anyone had success with it?